# Action Label On Text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uilabel

I have an Xcode project where I want to make an action label for names that is similar to mentions(@) and hashtags(#) labels where its bolded and I can press on it and it will send me to another view controller. I have search aroud for this and have only found cocoa pods that are for mentions and hashtags. **How do I implement this?**

Example: "**Mark Smith** liked your photo." Then I will be able to press on "Mark Smith" and it will send me to his profile.

Comment: You can use `UILabel`'s `attributedText` along with `NSMutableAttributedString`.

Comment: How do i integrate segue functions with that?

Comment: This is a little bit complicate. You can use a custom attribute for the highlighted text. If the user taps on the label you can use the finger position on the label to determine the string index in the attributed string. This will then allow you to determine whether the user has touched a location with your custom attribute. With this custom attribute you can now decide what to do.

Comment: I got the custom attribute down to make that section of the text bold. But the user tap part I have no idea how to do that. Also this text are apart of labels in tableview cells so I do not know if that changes anything but just to let you know. **How do I implement the user taps part?**

Comment: Give `UITapGestureRecognizer` a chance.

Comment: I have programmatically added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to my cell and have attached it to the label. Now whenever the user taps on the label, it transports them to the user's profile. But now how do I detect where the user presses? because like in the example in my question "Mark Smith liked your photo" I want it if the user press on mark smith it will send them to his profile but if they press on photo it will send them to the photo page. How do I detect this?

Comment: You can get the position with `location(in:)` from `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can replace UILabel with UITextView,run this simple code:

```
`func addLinkLabel() {
    let textView = UITextView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 150, width: 400, height: 100))
    self.view.addSubview(textView)

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "Touch me,you'll be sent to another ViewController.")
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "aa", range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: 8))
    textView.attributedText = attributedString
    textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20),
                                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.red]
    textView.isEditable = false
    textView.delegate = self;

}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    if String(describing: URL) == "aa"  {
        print("Here we go...")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController(), animated: true)
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

`

Comment: I will love to implement this in my project, but how do I make this work inside a tableview cell? I can't seem to get it right

Comment: Too busy recently and late reply,I will have a try.

Comment: I tried it just now,you can set a delegate for your customcell,and you will made it.`func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        
        if String(describing: URL) == "aa"  {
            print("Here we go...")
            
            self.delegate?.pushToNextViewController()
            return true
        }
        return false
    
    }
`

Comment: If I long press on a name, I get the options of "open", "copy", and "share" how do I turn these off too? Also sometimes when I press on the tableview I get the error: "_Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: ' '_ " how do I fix this?